# Need help to find multiple tagname's location

Tags: mysql, sql

- I have one table called areas, I have added areas with the tag fields i.e. , "Tourist, nightlife, West Ends, Dining" and many more.
- Now I have some Records, as follows

`Area        |   TagNames
------          -------------
New York        Tourist, NightLife
Switzerland     Tourist, Dining
London          NightLife, West Ends, Tourist
.               .
.               .
.               .
.               .`

I have such a field in table, Now my question is,

I want to find find areas which have tag name "Tourist" and "NightLife", can anyone tell me the query of it.
I know FIND_IN_SET will work, but it will work for a single record found. 
example `FIND_IN_SET("Tourist", TagNames)`, but for the multiple tagnames it will not work. So pleas tell me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First thing i would if its possible you can change your schema then normalize it on first priority,To answer you problem you need to use `FIND_IN_SET()` as many times the tags name you want to compare with and operator

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Tourist', TagNames) >0
AND  FIND_IN_SET('NightLife', TagNames) >0
and so on ... for multiple tags
```

[**Database Normalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

For above structure i would say you need to have one tag table which will store all tags and other table as junction table or say it as association table which will store multiple tags for each area again not in  a single row

Structure for tables

Area table

```
ID   name
1    xxx
```

Tag table

```
ID   name
1    xxx
2    yyy
```

Area tags

```
ID  area_id  tag_id
1    1        1
2    1        2
```

A join query

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM area a
JOIN area_tags at ON(a.ID=at.area_id)
JOIN tag t ON(t.ID=at.tag_id)
WHERE t.name IN('Tourist','NightLife')
GROUP BY a.ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT at.tag_id) >=2 /* which contains these tags with other if you need only these the change it to HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT at.tag_id) =2 */
```

Additional add index on `area_id,tag_id` and you are good to go

Comment: Thanks, but It takes too much time to execute. I already tried that one too. I want some optimize way. So if you have then please let me know.
Here, I just explain one or two tags, but in my example there are almost 10 tags search criteria. So it was taking too much time. Thats why I have posted this question

Comment: `area tags` `id` ought to be redundant, in which case DISTINCT would be redundant too!

Comment: Thanks again, But I don't want the way, that you have wrote the updated answers. I already have the same flow. But over system will gonna update, our client client had send us a database. And we have to work on that.

Comment: @user3540050: You can replace *FIND_IN_SET('Tourist', TagNames) >0* with *concat(', ', TagNames, ', ') like '%, Tourist, %'* and see if that speeds up the query (which I don't find likely). It's just as 
M Khalid Junaid said: the query is slow because you store the tags concatenated in a string rather than have them as separate entities which could be looked up much faster.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  This will not gonna work proper. Please read the question. There are no such a proper sequence for TagName field. Any kind of sequence will be there, and from that we have to execute query. So as I have knowledge, we must have to use FIND_IN_SET function. But if you have any other method to find, please tell me.

Comment: @user3540050: I suspected that all tags in that string are separated by comma plus blank. In case this is so, you could use M Khalid Junaid's query, but replace all FIND_IN_SET expressions with according LIKE expressions. Maybe LIKE is a little faster. However, as mentioned, I don't expect a real difference here. It's the table design that makes access slow. (A full table scan is done for every such query). If possible change the database design as suggested.